Can one prove locality principle for emulation of Abstract State Machine?
Suppose we emulate some ASM in memory machine, like RAM machine or Turing machine. One ASM postulates is Bounded Exploration Postulate, which seems related. Can one prove some form of locality principle for emulation of any ASM from that?

I recommend you [edit] your post to provide more context and background.  I suggest explaining what you mean by "Abstract State Machine" and "Bounded Exploration Postulate", and providing some background on what you mean by a locality principle.  Perhaps you can state an example of a claim that you conjecture might hold.

There is already link for article with definition for locality principle. I edited to add link for ASM, but I think someone without experience with them might not answer my question, cuz I am mostly looking for literature reference.

Fair enough, I understand that this might be hard to answer for people who are not already an expert on ASMs.  Still, I don't see a definition of "Bounded Exploration Postulate", or what "locality principle" might mean in this particular context.  Locality in computer science is a quite vague concept, and the paper you link to does not make it any more specific or precise or describe what you have in mind specifically for ASMs.
